# weird space between two modules on a joomla site

Tags: css

I'm having some issues with a joomla site i'm working on

http://dev.turnim.com/clients/dance/

below the fullscreen slideshow comes the company logo, and above the logo i have some really weird space. I tried everything i could think of in eliminating or adjusting the space, but firebug wasn't any help at all

The slideshow has his own module position and the company logo, incl the teaser text too

Any help, how to fix this, will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your custom.css or make one if you done't have one and add it

```
@media (min-width: 1220px)
     .tm-block-large .tm-headerbar + .tm-block, .tm-block-large .tm-fullscreen + .tm-block        {
     padding-top: 0px;
     }
```

if it doesn't work, add !important  at the end of it before the ;

debug, and voila!